# Stackdriver Debug Logpoint failing to trigger

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am debugging a Flask-based Python app in production and thought that Stackdriver logging might help. I followed this Google [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-stackdriver-debug/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) and successfully got both Debug Snapshots and logpoints working:

[image: codelabs logpoints are hit]

**For my Production project:**

The Snapshots work as expected - I can inspect the values of variables, etc. However, **Logpoint doesn't work** :(. 
That is, when I hit my application, the logpoint isn't triggered at all and I've searched all my logs and tried filtering using the keywords "logpoint" and "multithread" to match my logpoint:

[image: prod project logpoints not hitting]

I have enabled all the Stackdriver-related APIs on my GCP project:

[image: Stackdriver APIs enabled]

Any idea why my logpoints might be failing to trigger?

Comment: The enabling of APIs is good. Since it works with other application, It could maybe your application setting have an issue with our platform. 
Please check these documents[1](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/compute-engine-python)[2](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/add-log-statements-to-your-application-on-the-fly-with-Stackdriver-Debugger-Logpoints.html) that have more detail about setting Logpoint.